# cyclic representation of $L^∞(X, Ω, µ)$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, cyclic-groups

Let $(X, Ω, µ)$ be a measure space. For $ϕ ∈ L^∞(X, Ω, µ)$, set $π(ϕ)f := ϕf$ for $f ∈ L^2(X, Ω, µ)$.
Let $π(ϕ) ∈ B(L^2(X, Ω, µ))$, and that the map  $ϕ → π(ϕ)$  yields a representation
$π: L^∞(X, Ω, µ) → B(L^2(X, Ω, µ))$ of the $C^∗-algebra$ $L^∞(X, Ω, µ)$ on $L^2(X, Ω, µ)$.
Suppose that $µ$ is σ-finite.
(a) Show that π is a cyclic representation of $L^∞(X, Ω, µ)$.
(b) Determine the cyclic vectors for π.

I tried to solve this problem by relying on the fact $L^∞(X, Ω, µ)$ is dense in $L^2(X, Ω, µ)$. Also I want to show that: there is at least $e ∈ H$ Hilbert space such that $cl[π(A)e]=H$. But I am struggling with that, so I need help to solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that because $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite that the constant one function $1_X:X\to \mathbb{C}$ is contained in both $L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ and $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$. As you mentioned $L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ is dense in $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ so $L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)\cdot 1_X=L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ which is dense in $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$.

For the second part the following condition is necessary and sufficient; $h$ is cyclic if and only if $h$ is nonzero a.e.

$"\implies"$ Suppose that $h\in L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ is a cyclic vector. Then there exists a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ in $L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ such that $f_nh\to 1_X$ in $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$, implying that $h$ is nonzero a.e.

$"\impliedby"$ If $h$ is nonzero a.e. $1/h$ can be defined a.e. and $h\cdot 1/h=1_X$  in $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$. As a result $L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)h\subset L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)\cdot 1/h\cdot  h=L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)\cdot 1_X$ which is dense in $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$

Comment: Is the density condition enough to prove that π is a cyclic representation of $L^∞(X,Ω,µ)$ ?

Comment: Let $\pi:A\to B(H)$ be a representation of $C^{\ast}$ algebras, a vector $v\in H$ is said to be cyclic if $\pi(A)v$ is dense in $H$. In our case $L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)\cdot 1_X=L^{\infty}(X,\Omega,\mu)$ is dense in $L^{2}(X,\Omega,\mu)$.

Comment: In the second part you prove that h is cyclic vector and nonzero, but how can I determine the cyclic vectors for π. this is question.

Comment: The cyclic vectors are precisely the functions that are nonzero a.e.

Comment: For the first your comment that means $cl[π(A)e]=H$, is true?

Comment: Yes that is meant with the first comment.

Comment: @esteban why would a constant function be (square) integrable in general? That is, without a finite measure or some condition on the domain?